# What is the fastest way to retrieve a Xml node by ID

Tags: c#, search, tree, xmlnode

What is the fastest method to retrieve an XML node? I have an application that need the functionality of replace a specific node, when the document is small is fast but soon get bigger then it takes some several second to do the replacement. This is the method, I just do a brute force comparison that sucks real bad in that scenario.

```
public bool ReplaceWithAppendFile(string IDReplace)
{
    XElement UnionElement = (from sons in m_ExtractionXmlFile.Root.DescendantsAndSelf()
                             where sons.Attribute("ID").Value == IDReplace
                             select sons).Single();
    UnionElement.ReplaceWith(m_AppendXmlFile.Root.Elements());
    m_ExtractionXmlFile.Root.Attribute("MaxID").Value =
        AppendRoot.Attribute("MaxID").Value;
    if (Validate(m_ExtractionXmlFile, ErrorInfo))
    {
        m_ExtractionXmlFile.Save(SharedViewModel.ExtractionFile);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        m_ExtractionXmlFile = XDocument.Load(SharedViewModel.ExtractionFile);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could have a look at XPath, it's commonly used for purposes like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using XPath:

```
string xPath = string.Format("//*[@id='{0}']", IDReplace);
XElement UnionElement = m_ExtractionXmlFile.XPathSelectElement(xPath);
```

You may refer to [Finding Elements by Attributes in a DOM Document Using XPath](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/org.w3c.dom/xpath_GetElemByAttr.html) for more examples.

P.S. It is considered good convention to start names of parameters and local variables in lowercase. Thus, use `idReplace` and `unionElement` rather than the above.